# How to clean memory after UIImageView animation

Tags: ios, animation, memory-management, uiimageview, xcode-instruments

Here is my code:
Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *imageView;
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithImages;
}
- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cleanMemory:(id)sender;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

......

- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender {
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

    arrayWithImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic5"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic6"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic7"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic8"],nil];
    imageView.animationImages = arrayWithImages;
    imageView.animationDuration = 3;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    [imageView startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)cleanMemory:(id)sender {

    [arrayWithImages removeAllObjects];
    [arrayWithImages release];
    arrayWithImages= nil;

    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [imageView release];
    imageView = nil;
}
@end
```

I have `ViewController` and its `view` with two buttons. First button with `startAnimation` action, which creates `UIImageView` , `NSMutableArray` and starts animation on it. Second button with `cleanMemory` action , which clean all what i've created in `startAnimation`.
When i start `Profile` with `Activity Monitor` instrument, my program have `4 mb Real Mem`, when i press `startAnimation` button it's changes to `16 mb Real Mem` and after animation i press  `cleanMemory` button, but it has same `16 mb Real Mem`... Why? I wont to clean my memory to started value( 4 mb Real Mem). Please, can you explain, where i have problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImage imageNamed:` caches the images and will release the memory on it's own schedule. If you do not want the caching, that is completely control the memory then load the image directly,not with `UIImage imageNamed:`.

From the Apple docs:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the
>   resulting object.

You can use

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

to load the image directly.

From the Apple docs:

> This method does not cache the image object.

Answer (score 1):

If even after using `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` you still don't get to free memory, tyr calling `imageView.animationImages = nil;`